# Linear Algebra Find Matrix that satisfies the proposition

Tags: linear-algebra, projection, projection-matrices

Let (V, K) be a finite-dimensional vector space and φ ∈ L(V, V ). Find φ
such that if A is its matrix representation with respect to some basis of V ,
then $A^2(I − A) = 0$ but φ is not a projection. This problem shows you that
if a map φ satisfies the relation $φ^3 = φ^2$
, this does not necessarily imply that
φ is idempotent and hence a projection!
Hint: do not attempt to find the most general φ. It is sufficient to provide
an example for such a linear transformation in the case $(V, K) = (R^
2
, R)$.

I've tried to do this by chance and didn't get what satisfies this

Is there a proper way to solve this other than by luck

Answer (score 0):

You want to find some kind of linear map $\varphi$ such that $\varphi^2 \neq \varphi$ but does not change, when you apply it to itself again. Do you know a map $\alpha$ such that for all maps $\beta$ we always have $\alpha \circ \beta = \alpha$? If you have found one, can you find an $\varphi\neq \alpha$ such that $\varphi^2 = \alpha$?

Comment: I couldnt find , Could you help me finding one and what approach should I use

Comment: one approach that I took was to consider A=[2 1 ,-4 -2 ] so that A^2 = 0

Comment: Finding a $A$ such that $A^2=0$ is a good way. So we have $A^2\neq A$, so $A$ is no projection. And $A^3 = A^2 \circ A = 0 \circ A = 0 = A^2$. So you have found what you wanted. This property of $A$ is called nilpotency (or $A$ is nilpotent). The example $[0 1, 0 0]$ is a bit easier but your $A$ works as well.